How to add a new SSL certificate during runtime in QtwebEngine?
I would like to ask You, how is it possible to add a new SSL certificate into the nss database during runtime on Linux.
Webengine and chromium are using nss database. Chromium reads the database into memory via libnss. Even if the database is updated via certutil, my application needs to be restarted, which is unacceptable.
Does anyone have any suggestions on this ?
Version of Qt is 5.12.
The expected behavior should be that certificates should add at runtime without restarting the application.

Why do you need to add root certificates this often? Are they self-signed instead of generated by a common CA?
